# How can I download and send a file from firebase cloud storage before deletion?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

This is my current solution which is sending an empty file. I basically need to email a file before it gets deleted from a specific bucket

```
exports.sendBeforeDelete = functions.storage.bucket('reports').object().onDelete(async (object:any) => {
      const fileBucket = object.bucket; 
      if (fileBucket === 'reports') {
        const filePath = object.name;
        if (filePath) {
          const file = await request(`${object.mediaLink}&token=${object.metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens}`);
            const email = example@example.com
            const mailOptions = {
              from: 'example',
              to: email,
              subject: 'Report Deleted',
              text: ` Mail Body
              `,
              attachments: [{
                file
              }
              ]
            };
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error: any, info: any) {
              if (error) {
                console.log('error', error);
              } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
              }
            });

        }
      }
      return Promise.resolve()
    });
```

I have tried just using the object but never seem to get a valid file.

Comment: You're not dealing with promises and asynchronous programming correctly.  You're obliged to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  You can't just return `Promise.resolve()` to do that automatically.

Comment: Can you explain why this would affect the retrieval of the file at hand?

Comment: The function is terminating and cleaning up before any of the work finishes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code provided is indeed not dealing with promises and asynchronous programming correctly. Please attempt to return a resolved promise once the async work has been completed. You can do so through using the [Await operator](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb#:%7E:text=The%20await%20operator%20is%20used,not%20the%20whole%20program%20execution.).

This function terminates before any work has been done as you attempt to return Promise.resolve before the async work has completed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue we found was that the file was already deleted on this function

functions.storage.bucket('reports').object().onDelete()

so it was no longer accessible to us. instead we ran a cronjob at 6AM to check if a file was due to be deleted that day and then sent it then instead of on deletion of the file